# w3wp.exe crash - ThreadAbortException

Tags: .net-4.0, crash, windbg, crash-dumps, windows-server-2008-x64

we have a problem that we can't reproduce, it happens randomly on our web server (Windows Server 2008 Datacenter 64-bit, hosted on Amazon EC2) running ASP.NET 4.

**It starts with a ASP.NET warning in the error log (a strange GET request with a really long URL):**

> Exception information:
>      Exception type: HttpException
>      Exception message: The length of the URL for this request exceeds the configured maxUrlLength value.
>     at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

**Then an error:**

> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT
>   Process ID: 4604
>   Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>   Message: Thread was being aborted.
>   StackTrace:    at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
>     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
>     at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr managedHttpContext, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

**Then another error:**

> Application ID: DefaultDomain
>   Process ID: 4604
>   Exception: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>   Message: Thread was being aborted.
>   StackTrace:

**And then the application error:**

> Faulting application w3wp.exe, version 7.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e03238, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6002.18005, time stamp 0x49e041d1, exception code 0xe0434352, fault offset 0x00000000000176fd, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.

**Windbg**

I managed to get a dump for a crash with adplus, but I really don't know what to look for. I've troubleshooted some stackoverflows with Windbg before, but I don't know which approach to use for this error.

**!pe on the thread with the error:**

> Exception object: 00000001c323d948
>   Exception type:   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException
>   Message:          Thread was being aborted.
>   InnerException:   
>   StackTrace (generated):
>   
>   StackTraceString: 
>   HResult: 80131530

**!clrstack**

> Child SP         IP               Call Site
>   0000000015f7f078 0000000076c176fd [GCFrame: 0000000015f7f078]
>   0000000015f7f258 0000000076c176fd [GCFrame: 0000000015f7f258]

**k**

> Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
>   00000000`15f7edf0 000007fe`f2826e39 kernel32!RaiseException+0x39
>   00000000`15f7eec0 000007fe`f2bbbfb4 clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+0x363
>   00000000`15f7eff0 000007fe`f2bbc906 clr!RaiseTheException+0xa4
>   00000000`15f7f020 000007fe`f2c3b99b clr!BStrFromString+0x66
>   00000000`15f7f050 000007fe`f2c3b9a9 clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+0x3b
>   00000000`15f7f0c0 000007fe`f2c93156 clr!RealCOMPlusThrow+0x9
>   00000000`15f7f0f0 000007fe`f2b229f3 clr!Thread::RaiseCrossContextException+0x2a7
>   00000000`15f7f310 000007fe`f2830886 clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xafb03
>
>   00000000`15f7f4c0 000007fe`f27fcce3 clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+0x9e
>
>   00000000`15f7f530 000007fe`f845ba59 clr!UMThunkStubAMD64+0x273
>
>   00000000`15f7f5c0 000007fe`f8458f02 webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::ProcessNotification+0x79
>
>   00000000`15f7f5f0 000007fe`f27d4595 webengine4!ProcessNotificationCallback+0x43
>
>   00000000`15f7f620 000007fe`f27d3ac8 clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x181
>
>   00000000`15f7f6d0 000007fe`f294658f clr!ThreadpoolMgr::NewWorkerThreadStart+0x2e5
>
>   00000000`15f7f770 000007fe`f29447c6 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x3b
>
>   00000000`15f7f810 00000000`76c1be3d clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x7d
>
>   00000000`15f7fbd0 00000000`76d56a51 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xd
>
>   00000000`15f7fc00 00000000`00000000 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x1d

Anybody have a clue what this could be? Or can point me in the right direction for analyzing it with Windbg?

Edit:
The incoming urls usually looks like this:
foo.bar.com/wEPDwULLTE1MTk5MzIzMTFkGAMFFmN0bDAwJGRiMSRkZGxEYXRhYmFzZXMPFCsAAmRkZAU7Y3RsMDAkU2VhcmNoQ2xvdWQxJF9SaWdodENvbHVtbiRfU2VhcmNoQ2xvdWQkbHN2U2VhcmNoVGVybXMPFCsADmRkZGRkZGQ8KwAUAAIUZGRkZgL/D2QFK2N0bDAwJHN1cnZleTEkX1JpZ2h0Q29sdW1uJF9JUiR1c2VyQ29tbWVudHMPFCsAA2VnZGQeuUcvQDsShDIp1k7YjJw70Ry 9/Q1B9Sd1egrovYgkw==/

but I found in the event log that this happen for this urls like this aswell:
foo.bar.com/&
("dangerous request" in .NET 4)

Comment: Enable IIS logging to see the actual incoming url/query string.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least load symbols and then see the correct strings displayed in call stack.

If you are not capable of handling such analysis, I think opening a support case via http://support.microsoft.com is good for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to work out a similar issue.

I found this article which purports a process for determining the cause, I think it actually makes sense:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2012/06/21/how-to-troubleshoot-httpexception-request-timed-out-asp-net-4-0-64-bit.aspx

Caveat: I have not been able to sucessfully complete the steps described. I will be posting here asking for help.